# Grep down to up without tac

Tags: shell, grep, reverse, cat, tail

I have a file with about 30.000.000 lines (Radius Accounting) and I need to find the some pattern from down to up, because I need the last result.

The command:

```
tac accounting.log | grep $pattern
```

gives what I need, but it's too slow because at first the OS has to read the whole file and then send to pipe.

So, I need something fast that read the file from the last line to first.

Thanks and sorry my English.

Comment: Did you try using `cat` ?

Comment: @miNde I want you read de the file from down to up, not up to down.

Comment: If the filesystem (like ext4) allows it, `tac` will seek from the end of the file, rather than reading the whole file. But yes, this is filesystem dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@anubhava's answer is a great in that if you know the pattern will be in the last X lines you can use `tail -n X`.  However if you don't know the X value you have a couple of options.

1) Instead of trying to modify the tac command, modify the grep command to only match the first (this saves computational time because grep doesn't have to process the whole file).

```bsh
tac accounting.log | grep -m 1 $pattern
```

2)  Write a `for` loop that processes the file line by line backwards and then breaks from that for loop once you have found what you want.

Comment: Hello Andrew Cassidy and @anubhava, do you know if tac will sends the lines to grep like a stream or if the Operation System has to read the whole file and then sends to grep?

Comment: +1 for the clever combination of `tac` (OSX users: use `tail -r`) and grep's `-m <count>` option.

Comment: tac dumps the backward contents of the file to standard output and grep processes that dump through standard input... my for loop suggestion would bypass this process of passing around the whole file.

Comment: Using your firt suggestion "_grep -m1_" the execution time goes from **0m0.597s to 0m0.007s** \o/.
Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `tac` you can use `tail -r`.

For example use this command to read last 100 lines backwards and find patterns using grep:

```
tail -n 100 -r accounting.log | grep "$pattern"
```

Comment: Note that `tail -r` does not work on all platforms (OSX supports it, but at least some Linux distros don't - conversely, `tac` - which doesn't support limiting the number of lines - is not available on OSX).